# Is beamer counted as a bouncer in ODI cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is beamer counted as a bouncer in ODI cricket? I.e. if a bowler bowls a beamer then whether he is allowed to bowl a bouncer in that over?

Comment: @Spinner - I really searched hard in Cricket laws, ICC Match Playing Conditions, Wikipedia etc but couldn't find any specification regarding this. I think the only option is to find out from the real match commentary/video. I will try to find it later. So I have deleted the answer right now.

Comment: @hims056 Fair enough. If there's nothing in the Laws or Playing Conditions to indicate that a beamer is counted as a bouncer, I'm inclined to believe that a beamer is not counted as one.

Answer (score 2):

No.  A beamer is an immediate no ball and does not count toward any part of the over.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28cricket%29):

> This type of delivery can result in injuries to the batsman, and the
>   penalty for this type of delivery is an immediate no-ball signal given
>   by the umpire. The use of beamers is governed under Law 42.6.

Comment: An immediate no ball is a law for a beamer. But does it *also* count as one of the bouncer? There is no specification in the given reference.

Comment: No, a no-ball could not be counted as one of the bouncers because that only counts legal deliveries.